# localStorage, saving a class using toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, toggleclass

I am  clueless when it comes to localStorage it seems. I want to set up a way favorite any div in a group of div's by toggling a class. I can get the toggleClass to work on the individual div and be saved but localStorage saves all the div's as favorites, not just the one with the toggleClass set. Obviously I am missing something.

[jsfiddle simple example](http://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/WvmOBE)

localStorage code:

```
if (typeof (localStorage) == 'undefined') {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.';
} else {
if (localStorage.getItem("fav") != null) {
    getFav = localStorage.fav;
    $(".item").addClass('favorites');
}
}
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    getFav = localStorage.fav;
    //$(".item").removeClass('favorites');
    //localStorage.removeItem('background');
    $(this).closest(".item").toggleClass('favorites');
    if ($(this).closest(".item").hasClass('favorites')) {
    localStorage.setItem('fav', 'favorites');

}else{
    localStorage.removeItem('fav');
}

});
});
```

The issue resides in

```
$(".item").addClass('favorites');
```

It adds the class to all .items and obviously it should not.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `$(".item").addClass('favorites')` adds the *"favorite"* class to **all** *"item"* classed elements

Comment: I realize that, and that is why I am asking for help with the code. I can toggle individually, but not save in localStorage individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the other answers questions do not suffice here is a solution that allows you to have multiple divs that will maintain state after reload rather than just one.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvmEbX

```
if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined') {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    'Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.';
} else {
    $(".item").each(function(i, el) {
      if (localStorage['fav' + i] == 'favorites') {
        $(this).addClass('favorites');
      }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var $item = $(this).closest('.item');
    var index = $('.item').index($item);
    $item.toggleClass('favorites');
    if ($item.hasClass('favorites')) {
      localStorage.setItem('fav' + index, 'favorites');
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('fav' + index);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `class` HTML `divs` try using the `ID` property instead of using `class`, however make sure you specify two different `ID`s as currently the classes are clashing.

```
<div id="testOne" class="item">Test
      <div class="holder">
          <button class="btn">Toggle</button>
      </div>
</div>


<div id="testTwo" class="item">Test
      <div class="holder">
          <button class="btn">Toggle</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have assigned the `ID` property to each one, now you'd add a style to that specific `ID` so that way they don't clash.

Comment: I made the example very simple. but in use, the div's will have the same class and setting different ID's is too cumbersome, due to the number of them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply to a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31910649/3176651) *(ID's are too cumbersome)*

Here is another approach. You can use their `index` as the `localStorage` value. **HOWEVER**, the number of the `item` elements must not change AND they don't change ordering.

```
if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined') {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    'Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.';
} else {
  // highlight the selected item
  if (localStorage.getItem("fav") != null) {
    getFav = localStorage.fav;
    $('.item').eq(getFav).addClass('favorites');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    getFav = localStorage.fav;

    // clear all highlights
    $(".item").removeClass('favorites');

    // get the selected item then its index, then store in getFav
    var selectedItem = $(this).closest(".item");
    getFav = $('.item').index(selectedItem);
    selectedItem.toggleClass('favorites');

    // store the value in localStorage
    if (selectedItem.hasClass('favorites')) {
      localStorage.setItem('fav', getFav);
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('fav');
    }

  });
});
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJYroL

**NOTE** I really recommend that you apply ID to the elements if you can. That will be more flexible. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input on id's and your code. I'll consider it. The problem with  the above code for me is that it only allows selecting one "favorite", not  2 or more. I don't want to only toggleClass on one.