# How can I have a button save any changes made to local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

[An answer](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvmEbX) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910635/localstorage-saving-a-class-using-toggleclass) makes it possible to save a toggled class on specific objects to local storage, which was helpful, but not exactly what I need. And I'm not that great at modifying code when there aren't a lot of explanatory comments.

This is the answerer's JS:

```
if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined') {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    'Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.';
} else {
$(".item").each(function(i, el) {
  if (localStorage['fav' + i] == 'favorites') {
    $(this).addClass('favorites');
  }
});
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var $item = $(this).closest('.item');
    var index = $('.item').index($item);
    //$(".item").removeClass('favorites');
    //localStorage.removeItem('background');
    $item.toggleClass('favorites');
    if ($item.hasClass('favorites')) {
      console.log(index)
      localStorage.setItem('fav' + index, 'favorites');
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('fav' + index);
    }
  });
});
```

But I'm hoping there's a way to have a button that saves any changes that have been made to the page. I'm working on a page that is very interactive and has contenteditable elements, expandable menus, and highlightable paragraphs. I'd like there to be a save button that saves edited text, which menu is open, and which paragraphs are highlighted.

Is there a way to do this without having to edit the jquery for each interactive element?

Comment: I clicked through your profile after helping with that regex question and think I can help you with this as well. Without really seeing what the page looks like and how it's being modified it's hard to answer this question. Is there a particular reason you're not using a server-side service like a REST API to save the data to a database? Is there a need for local storage?

Comment: Well, the big picture is that I'm working on a prototype for a site that will eventually be linked to a server (a professional service will do it for me, I don't know any server-side code). For the sake of demonstrative purposes, I was hoping I could have a button that would allow me to show people how the "save your place" function would work. If it's too difficult, I might just have to wait until I can do it server-side.

Comment: @Cleo By any changes, do you mean to your JS variables? Or something else? Because if it is JS variables, the solution is easy to do and understand...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want a way to save the whole page state to local storage.

If I were going to do that I would probably make a different local storage item for each element that needs a state just to keep things distinctly organized.

So you need a way to convert your state to a local storage string and parse it back into the state after

Holding your state in an object like this could work

```
state = {
    'menu1': 'open',
    'menu2': 'closed',
    'textinput1': {'text': '' /*put text here*/, 'highlighted': '57-159'} //characters 57-159 are highlighted
}
//or if you want things to be as simple as possible
state = {
    'menu1': 'open',
    'menu2': 'closed',
    'textinput1-text': '' /*put text here*/,
    'textinput1-highlighted: '57-159'} 
}
//and then reading through the state
for (item in state) {
    if (state.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        //convert the state into a single string for each item
        //then set the local storage item
        localStorage.setItem(item,stringstate)
    }
}
```

Just be wary though if you did what I did above with 'textinput1' (where it actually holds an object of its own). You will probably want to give each of those internal items their own local storage item like this:

```
'textarea1-text' and 'textarea1-highlighted'
```

If you don't work with a single state like this already it may be difficult to rework your code to do this, but it will make it easier to add new things to local storage if you hold all of those things

Or if you have multiple components in your webpage you can have a state for each component

Converting the local storage item back into state:

```
for (item in state) {
    if (state.hasOwnProperty(item){
        state.item = localStorage.getItem(item)
    }
```

Then whenever you want to save the state to local storage it is easy since you already have the state for everything
You can have the state update any time a single change is made to anything on the webpage, or if the state only matters if the user is trying to save it, you can have the state update all at once when the button is clicked and then immediately save it to local storage

I hope this helps some, sorry if this isn't the method you were looking for

edit:

Sorry that the idea of state was so confusing, I probably did a poor job of explaining what I meant. So you want to have a button save any changes that were made by saving them to local storage. The toggle idea you got from that other person's answer can be useful for things like if a menu is open or closed since it can only be in an 'on' or 'off' position, but if you want to save text and what text is highlighted then you certainly need to save more info than that.

You said you have all of these elements like menus and text elements. You can have a single object (name it whatever you want). Let's call it state for now.

So

```
var state = {}
```

That object is a single place where you can store all of the different states for various elements. You can have a state for if a menu is open or closed easily.

If the jquery event that toggles the menu open (or however you have that event being trigger), goes off, just have it save whatever happened to the state object.
Here is a rough example to show the concept. Let's say you have some menu like thing and you toggle it open and closed using the jquery `show()` and `hide()` functions.

```
var state = {
     menu1: false
}

//A function you call whenever the menu button is clicked
function menuToggle() {
    if (state.menu1) {
        $('#menu1').hide()
    } else {
        $('#menu1').show()
    }
    //now update the state change
    state.menu1 = !state.menu1
}
```

Now let's say you have some function that is called whenever you want to save the changes to local storage

```
saveToLocalStorage() {
    for (item in state) {
        if (state.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            //make sure only to save the state[item] if it is a string or can doesn't lose meaning if converted to a string
            localStorage.setItem(item, state[item])
        }
    }
}
```

That code will run through every item in state and save it to local storage

Upon loading the page you can check local storage

```
loadFromLocalStorage() {
    var storedItem
    //loop through all of the properties in state
    for (item in state) {
        if (state.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            storedItem = localStorage.getItem(item)
            if (storedItem !== null) {
                //the state now holds whatever was in local storage
                state[item] = storedItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry again if I didn't simplify things enough. The question you asked requires that you have some way to check all of the things that you want saved to local storage, so if you put all of that information in one object then it is easy to save it all since it is already in one place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I don't really understand how I could incorporate this into my code. I'm not using 'single states', like you said. I'm very new to jQuery, and know practically nothing about JS, so even after reading this 3 times I still don't get it. Is this a basic JS theory I could grasp if I ran through a quick online course? Or is this something more specific? Maybe you can point me towards a demo somewhere for writing my code like this?

Comment: Sorry that was so confusing, I can understand how it would be, it was for me when I learned it. It is actually something utilized in the javascript library [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) which is where I first learned about the idea of a state. But it is a helpful way to write code even just in plain JS. I'll try to add a little more to explain what I mean at the bottom of my answer