# Follow/unfollow to remember the click of the button. Not working after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a follow/unfollow user on button click. However the current code only works until the page refreshes. If I refresh the page the follow text comes back. I want it to have unfollow when I refresh the page.

Do I need to have a Session for users in my PHP? Do I have to create a value for a button? Will it remember the click by multiple users?

```html
<button class="user">Follow</button>
<p></p>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'echocurrent.php',
    success: function(data) {
      $("p").text(data);
    }
  });
});

$('.user').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('user');

  if ($this.hasClass('user')) {
    //unfollows
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'UnFollow.php',
      success: function(data) {
        $("p").text(data);
      }
    });

    $this.text('Follow');
  } else {
    //follows
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'follow.php',
      success: function(data) {
        $("p").text(data);
      }
    });
    $this.text('UnFollow');
  }
});
```

UPDATE :

I want to add this jquery to every user with a session in PHP.
How can I do that?

Comment: Unfollow actions should change some values in DB, then once reloaded page should be properly rerendered by server/client side code. Since it doesn't then I would say this is you main problem why you render stale data.

Comment: Because the button has class `user` it will always set its text to 'Follow'

Comment: Yes store the state somewhere like localstorage. Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910635/localstorage-saving-a-class-using-toggleclass

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're updating a value in "UnFollow.php" you should return this value in "echocurrent.php" and based on it show/hide the class "user"

Update:
add logic to in "echocurrent.php" to return both the number of followers and if the current user is following this user

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'echocurrent.php',
    success: function(data) {
      $("p").text(data.followers);
      if(data.isFollowing){
        $this.toggleClass('user');
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: the echocurrent.php shows the current no of follows and UnFollow.php is used to unfollow the user.